# How is SndVol able to change the volume level of a given audio session?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, core-audio, wasapi

I am writing my own API to perform some of the functionality of the SndVol system utility. I would like part of this API to be the ability to set the volume level of a given [audio session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678707.aspx).

SndVol displays a slider on the "Device" panel that the user can use to change the master volume level of the audio device as well as a slider for each audio session (on the "Applications" panel) that changes the volume level of the session:

[image: Screenshot of SndVol Volume Mixer]

If I drag the slider handle for one of the audio sessions, then SndVol is able to change the audio session's volume level. How does it do that?

I thought that it was possible using Windows Vista's [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370805%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but I encountered the problem that although I am able to iterate audio sessions of a device using an [`IAudioSessionEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368281%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the `IAudioSessionEnumerator` only gives me access to [`IAudioSessionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368246%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) objects, but I need the [`IAudioClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370865%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object to obtain an [`ISimpleAudioVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316531%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object that I can use to set the audio session volume level. Is it possible to get the `IAudioClient` object associated with an `IAudioSessionControl` object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you call QueryInterface on the IAudioSessionControl interface, you can often get access to an ISimpleAudioVolume.

Comment: God, why must everything Microsoft be so convoluted.. ?

Comment: @hauzer Sometimes it is a way to discourage moving to different platforms due to invested time learning the API and not wanting to relearn yet another learning curve elsewhere; sometimes it's just difficult to create simple naming conventions for functions or methods, particularly when dealing with OOP that may have a large object model.

Comment: Not so much convoluted as undocumented. How would I know that these are often the same?

Answer (score 2):

[Larry Osterman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/), who works for Microsoft and worked on the new audio API stuff, wrote a series of blog posts about the new Vista/Win7 audio features. Here are a few links that might help:

[A Quick Run-through the new Windows 7 Multimedia/Audio SDK Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2009/08/07/a-quick-run-through-the-new-windows-7-multimedia-audio-sdk-samples.aspx) - Sample shows per-app volume control

[Volume Control in Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/12/15/504158.aspx) - Describes per-application volume control and other new audio features that were added in Vista/Win7

There's an index on the right side of the page; you can look at the [Audio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/tags/Audio/) tagged items for some other articles that might help.