# Enumerate Audio Sessions in Windows

Tags: c++, wasapi, windows-10-sdk

I would like to enumerate all Audio Sessions with Windows Audio Core APIs and be able to manipulate the Sessions Volumes, but I can't find a way to enumerate the audio sessions and get some Interface like the [`ISimpleAudioVolume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume) Interface. I can only enumerate the `IAudioSessionManager2` to get the [`IAudioSessionControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol) Interfaces for all running sessions. But this interface only enables me to get the icons and descriptions. But no option to get the session guid. In order to get the `ISimpleAudioVolume` of a session I need the session guid to make use of [`IAudioSessionManager::GetSimpleAudioVolume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager-getsimpleaudiovolume).

Edit: I may get the proper guid from [`IAudioSessionControl::GetGroupingParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol-getgroupingparam) but I get 12 audio sessions. Why do I get so many sessions, when sndvol only displays 3 outputs?

**How do I enumerate all running audio sessions and get the `ISimpleAudioVolume` Interfaces for them?**

I've got instances of [`IAudioSessionManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager) and [`IAudioSessionManager2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager2) available.

Comment: Related: [How can I programmatically set the default input and output audio device for an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778069/how-can-i-programmatically-set-the-default-input-and-output-audio-device-for-an)

Comment: @Mitch Unfortunately this only enumerates devices, not the sessions

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager2-getsessionenumerator

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, but as I stated above, I have used it and still cannot get the correct interfaces

Comment: I don't see you mention it anywhere.  Show your code.

Comment: @HansPassant Quote from above:
> I can only enumerate the IAudioSessionManager2 to get the IAudioSessionControl Interfaces for all running sessions. But this interface only enables me to get the icons and descriptions.

Comment: [If you call `QueryInterface` on the `IAudioSessionControl` interface, you can often get access to an `ISimpleAudioVolume`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084029/868014)

Comment: @RomanR. You are my hero, thank you!